# NaNs in extracting climate data from raster

Tags: r, gis, geospatial, netcdf, r-raster

I am trying to extract PDSI (Palmer Drought Severity Index) values from a .nc file, and I get mysterious NaN values for some of my locations.  The spatial point data are plot locations across the USA.  They are lat/lon in decimal degrees using NAD 83 datum.

The PDSI data are available here: https://wrcc.dri.edu/wwdt/data/PRISM/pdsi/.
download files  pdsi_6_PRISM.nc, pdsi_7_PRISM.nc, and pdsi_8_PRISM.nc.  These are historical data for the entire USA by month (from 1895-2022; 6 for June, 7 for July, and 8 for August).  They are in the WSG84 projection.

For each location (n=~102,000), I have lat/lon data
(the data are here, dumped from R: https://www.dropbox.com/s/xlfh7ubkwlie1ws/dump_pdsi_data.R?dl=0).
I want to calculate a "baseline" value (the average from 1970-1990, for June, July, and August), then calculate the average over the interval ("growInt") between two years (MEASTIME_t1, and MEASTIME_t2, again for June, July, and August), and finally take the difference between the two.

The code seems to be doing what is intended, however, I am getting several locations with NaN .  Does anybody know why that may be?  Does it have to do with the location data being NAD 83 and the pdsi data being WSG84?

```
## libraries
library(ncdf4) # package for netcdf manipulation
library(raster) # package for raster manipulation
library(rgdal) # package for geospatial analysis
library(ggplot2) # package for plotting 
library(sp)

### read in the data -  limit to growing season - June, July and August - 
pdsi6 <- nc_open("pdsi_6_PRISM.nc")
pdsi7 <- nc_open("pdsi_7_PRISM.nc")
pdsi8 <- nc_open("pdsi_8_PRISM.nc")


## GET LAT LON and DAY limits for each dataset 
### 6 = AUGUST, 7 = JUNE, 8 = JULY 
lat.6 <- ncvar_get(pdsi6, "latitude", verbose = F)
lon.6 <- ncvar_get(pdsi6, "longitude")
day.6 <- ncvar_get(pdsi6, "day")
###
lat.7 <- ncvar_get(pdsi7, "latitude", verbose = F)
lon.7 <- ncvar_get(pdsi7, "longitude")
day.7 <- ncvar_get(pdsi7, "day")
###
lat.8 <- ncvar_get(pdsi8, "latitude", verbose = F)
lon.8 <- ncvar_get(pdsi8, "longitude")
day.8 <- ncvar_get(pdsi8, "day")
###

## store the data in a 3-dimensional array
pdsi.array.6 <- ncvar_get(pdsi6)
pdsi.array.7 <- ncvar_get(pdsi7) 
pdsi.array.8 <- ncvar_get(pdsi8) 

## make -9999s (fill value) to NAs
pdsi.array.6[pdsi.array.6 == -9999] <- NA
pdsi.array.7[pdsi.array.7 == -9999] <- NA
pdsi.array.8[pdsi.array.8 == -9999] <- NA



## convert to raster bricks    
r_brick.6 <- brick(pdsi.array.6, xmn=min(lat.6), xmx=max(lat.6), ymn=min(lon.6), ymx=max(lon.6), crs=CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs+ towgs84=0,0,0"))

r_brick.7 <- brick(pdsi.array.7, xmn=min(lat.7), xmx=max(lat.7), ymn=min(lon.7), ymx=max(lon.7), crs=CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs+ towgs84=0,0,0"))

r_brick.8 <- brick(pdsi.array.8, xmn=min(lat.8), xmx=max(lat.8), ymn=min(lon.8), ymx=max(lon.8), crs=CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs+ towgs84=0,0,0"))



## start with null dataframe
source("dump_pdsi_data.R")


##################################################### START FOR LOOP
### for loop to extract time-series data for each plot location
for(i in 1:length(pdsi_data$pltID)){
  
  ### extract values 
  pdsi_vec.6 <- extract(r_brick.6, 
                        SpatialPoints(cbind(pdsi_data$LAT[i], pdsi_data$LON[i])), method='simple')
  
  pdsi_vec.7 <- extract(r_brick.7, 
                       SpatialPoints(cbind(pdsi_data$LAT[i], pdsi_data$LON[i])), method='bilinear') 
                                        
  pdsi_vec.8 <- extract(r_brick.8, 
                        SpatialPoints(cbind(pdsi_data$LAT[i], pdsi_data$LON[i])), method='bilinear')
  
  # sp::spTransform(SpatialPoints(cbind(pdsi_data$LAT[i], pdsi_data$LON[i]), proj4string=CRS("+init=epsg:4269 +proj=longlat +ellps=GRS80 +datum=NAD83 +no_defs +towgs84=0,0,0")), CRSobj = crs(r_brick.8))
  
  
  ### add year names to the vector 
  names(pdsi_vec.6) <- lubridate::year(as.Date("1900-01-01") + day.6)
  names(pdsi_vec.7) <- lubridate::year(as.Date("1900-01-01") + day.7)
  names(pdsi_vec.8) <- lubridate::year(as.Date("1900-01-01") + day.8)
  
  ### calculate the average baseline value 1970-1990
  pdsi_data$pdsi_baseline[i] <- mean(c(pdsi_vec.6[76:96], pdsi_vec.7[76:96], pdsi_vec.8[76:96]), na.rm = T)
  
  ### calculate the mean over the growth interval
  pdsi_data$pdsi_growInt[i] <- mean(c(as.vector(pdsi_vec.6[names(pdsi_vec.6) %in% 
                                                             seq(floor(pdsi_data$MEASTIME_t1[i]), floor(pdsi_data$MEASTIME_t2[i]))]), 
                                      as.vector(pdsi_vec.7[names(pdsi_vec.7) %in% 
                                                             seq(floor(pdsi_data$MEASTIME_t1[i]), floor(pdsi_data$MEASTIME_t2[i]))]), 
                                      as.vector(pdsi_vec.8[names(pdsi_vec.8) %in% 
                                                             seq(floor(pdsi_data$MEASTIME_t1[i]), floor(pdsi_data$MEASTIME_t2[i]))])),
                                    na.rm = T)

} ## end for loop
#####################################################

## make column for difference
pdsi_data$DeltaPDSI <-  pdsi_data$pdsi_growInt - pdsi_data$pdsi_baseline
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a solution to this issue by using the `terra` package.
Importing the data as rasters instead of netcdf files may have also fixed the issue. Using `terra::extract` rather than `raster::extract` returned data from the rasters with no NaN values.  I am not too sure why that is, but it fixed the issue.

I also learned that NAD 83 and WSG84 can be treated as exchangeable projections. See this quote from [NCEAS Overview of Coordinate Reference Systems (CRS) in R](https://nceas.ucsb.edu/sites/default/files/2020-04/OverviewCoordinateReferenceSystems.pdf)

> Transforming between NAD83 and WGS84 typically isn’t recommended for most >applications because standard transformations can introduce error that is >large relative to their difference.  Complicating the matter, the difference >between NAD83 and WGS84 varies with time and location.

```
## libraries
library(terra)

### read in the data - as rasters from terra package -  limit to growing season - June, July and August - 
pdsi6 <- rast("pdsi_6_PRISM.nc")
names(pdsi6) <- as.character(1895:2022)

pdsi7 <- rast("pdsi_7_PRISM.nc")
names(pdsi7) <- as.character(1895:2022)

pdsi8 <- rast("pdsi_8_PRISM.nc")
names(pdsi8) <- as.character(1895:2022)

## start with null dataframe
source("dump_pdsi_data.R")

## makes spatVector for spatial points of plot locations
pts <- vect(cbind(pdsi_data$LON, pdsi_data$LAT), crs="+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")

##################################################### START FOR LOOP
### for loop to extract time-series data for each plot location
for(i in 1:length(pdsi_data$pltID)){
  
  ### extract values 
  pdsi_vec.6 <- unlist(terra::extract(pdsi6, pts[i]))
  
  pdsi_vec.7 <- unlist(terra::extract(pdsi7, pts[i]))
  
  pdsi_vec.8 <- unlist(terra::extract(pdsi8, pts[i]))
  
  ### calculate the average baseline value 1970-1990
  pdsi_data$pdsi_baseline[i] <- mean(c(pdsi_vec.6[as.character(rep(1970:1990))], 
                                       pdsi_vec.7[as.character(rep(1970:1990))], 
                                       pdsi_vec.8[as.character(rep(1970:1990))]), 
                                     na.rm = T)
  
  ### calculate the mean over the growth interval
  pdsi_data$pdsi_growInt[i] <- mean(c(pdsi_vec.6[names(pdsi_vec.6) %in% 
                                                             seq(floor(pdsi_data$MEASTIME_t1[i]), floor(pdsi_data$MEASTIME_t2[i]))], 
                                      pdsi_vec.7[names(pdsi_vec.7) %in% 
                                                             seq(floor(pdsi_data$MEASTIME_t1[i]), floor(pdsi_data$MEASTIME_t2[i]))], 
                                      pdsi_vec.8[names(pdsi_vec.8) %in% 
                                                             seq(floor(pdsi_data$MEASTIME_t1[i]), floor(pdsi_data$MEASTIME_t2[i]))]),
                                    na.rm = T)

} ## end for loop
#####################################################

## make column for difference
pdsi_data$DeltaPDSI <-  pdsi_data$pdsi_growInt - pdsi_data$pdsi_baseline
```